# How to avoid error 500 on Nextjs API on client-side fetch?

Tags: json, api, async-await, next.js, prisma

I have the following API to get the user's data based on a [pid]:

```
import prisma from "../../../../lib/prisma";

// Master read function - API route includes profile, subnodes and contents
async function getProfile(req, res) {
    const profilePID = await prisma.profileNode.findUnique({
        where: {
            userName: req.query.pid
        },
        include: {
            subnode: {
                include: {
                    content: true,
                }
            },
        },
    })
    // Integer for how many accounts the current user is following
    const followingCount = await prisma.follower.count({
        where: {
            followerId: profilePID.userId
        },
        select: {
            profileId: true
        }
    })

    // integer for how many accounts the current user is being followed
    const followerCount = await prisma.follower.count({
        where: {
            profileId: profilePID.userId
        },
        select: {
            profileId: true
        }
    })

    // detailed profile info of the people you are following
    const following = await prisma.follower.findMany({
        where: {
            followerId: profilePID.userId,
            NOT: {
                profileId: null,
            }
        },
        include: {
            followees: true
        }
    })

    // aggregate all data queries into one
    const aggregatedData = {
        profilesYouAreFollowing: followingCount.profileId,
        yourProfileFollowers: followerCount.profileId,
        followingData: following,
        profileData: profilePID
    }

    if (aggregatedData) {
        res.status(200).json(aggregatedData)
    } else {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' })
    }
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    // commit to the database
    if (req.method === 'GET') {
        return getProfile(req, res)
    }
}
```

As you would observe, the first request is to find the profileNode using a [pid] - which is a string like localhost:3000/user/ABC. Then I would get the userId (an integer) within the profileNode. The userId is then used in the rest of the prisma query to the database for followers and followers' details since all the ids are stored as integer.

I used SWR for client-side fetch, which is all fine but I noticed that while fetching, it will cause an error 500 before the data is fully fetched.

[image]

Now, while this does not hinder data fetching for presenting data to the client since SWR takes care of error handling and continue fetching until all the data is acquired, however, it does throw an error on other code like JSON.parse, as the error 500 has passed an `undefined` value to it - thus throwing an error.

[image]

Any tips or tricks as to how to get rid of the error 500?

Added client side code below:

```
const { data, error } = useSWR(`/api/profiles/read/${slug}`, fetcher)
  const [subnodes, setSubnodes] = useState();

  // authentication using next-auth session and fetched client-side userId
  // compare equality - if equal, set Auth to true and show edit components
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchingData() {
      setLoading(true);
      // session
      const session = await getSession();
      let sessionUserId;
      if (!session) {
        sessionUserId = null;
      } else {
        sessionUserId = session.user.id;
      }

      // client
      const clientId = await data?.profileData.userId;

      // authentication check
      if (sessionUserId !== clientId) {
        setAuth(false);
      } else {
        setAuth(true);
      }

      async function asyncStringify(str) {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(str));
      }

      const awaitJson = await asyncStringify(data?.profileData.subnode)

      setSubnodes(awaitJson);

      setLoading(false)
    }
    fetchingData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: @juliomalves Added. I think it might be a problem with the API itself but I can't be certain, as that's more of a gut feeling.

Comment: All in all, I am trying to handle ```undefined``` in JSON.parse by setting it up as an asynchronous operation. But it still fails and throw an error. So I am quite lost as to how to approach this.

Comment: You should add `data` to the `useEffect`'s dependencies array, and also check that whatever you pass to `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` is not undefined before doing operations on it.